# Eclipse Change Colors in Color Theme?

Tags: eclipse

I tried to use the Oblivion color theme in my eclipse. It works fine the problem is that for groovy files characters like {},.:;= etc cannot be seen.

This is an example from a groovy file.

[image]

**What do I have to change to change the color for characters like {},.:;=?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is path for change syntax color of Java in Eclipse:

> Window/Preferences/Java/Editor/Syntax coloring

for JavaScript:

> Window/Preferences/JavaScript/Editor/Syntax coloring

In this place you can find Brackets and many other adjust...

I've checked these adjust in Eclipse Juno.

Comment: How do I change the syntax for groovy file?

Comment: Please try to change both syntax relevant coloring property. I use different color theme (MoonRise) and works to me.

Comment: I had a similar problem with pydev and this answer pointed in the right direction. In that case one can edit the format/color of specific characters from `Preferences>Pydev>Editor`.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that colors can be changed through Window/Preferences/General/Appearance/Colors And Fonts. You can also change highlight of matching symbols like [] () {} <> to white, not sure if that would help.

Comment: Which property do I have to change?